# How to configure I2S with ESP32 and MAX98357A to reproduce wav files?

Tags: esp32, sound

I have configured I2S to reproduce files with an ESP32 and a MAX98357A from and SD card. The problem is that it reproduces the files way too fast, like they are sped up * 100. Here is my (simplified) code:

```cpp
#define I2S_DOUT 25
#define I2S_BCLK 27
#define I2S_LRC 26

void setup() {
// Start SD card and sqlite
  SPI.begin();
  if (!SD.begin()) {
    Serial.println("SD card not found");
    while (1) {};
  }
// Configure I2S
  i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
      .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
      .sample_rate = 44100,
      .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
      .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT,
      .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB,
      .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
      .dma_buf_count = 2,
      .dma_buf_len = 1024,
      .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
  };

  i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
      .bck_io_num = I2S_BCLK,
      .ws_io_num = I2S_LRC,
      .data_out_num = I2S_DOUT,
      .data_in_num = -1,
  };

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
  i2s_set_dac_mode(I2S_DAC_CHANNEL_RIGHT_EN);
  i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, 44100);
}

void loop() {
// Play the audio file
  string filename = "/audios/" + text + ".wav";
  File file = SD.open(filename.c_str());
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  const size_t buffer_size = 512;
  uint8_t buffer[buffer_size];
  size_t bytes_read;
  size_t bytes_written;
  while (file.available() && (bytes_read = file.read(buffer, buffer_size)) > 0) {
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, buffer, bytes_read, &bytes_written, portMAX_DELAY);
    if (bytes_read == 0) break;
  }
  file.close();
}
```

How do I configure it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out (a somewhat long time ago) but forgot to post here hahaha.

Basically, the `i2s_config_t` was not properly configured. Here's a corrected version:

```cpp
i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
      .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
      .sample_rate = 44100,
      .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
      .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
      .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB,
      .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
      .dma_buf_count = 8,
      .dma_buf_len = 1024,
      .use_apll = false,
      .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
  };
```

If you compare, the `.channel_format` configuration changes from `I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_RIGHT_LEFT` to `I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT`. This is important because when using `RIGHT_LEFT` and only using one amplifier, 2 sound outputs were sent but only one amp was receiving them, causing the sound to play at twice the speed. Now, the `.dma_buf_count` was increased to 8, and added the `.use_apll` config, because I saw it somewhere else, I don't really know what it does hahaha.

There are other things.
In the setup for the i2s communication, I didn't include

```cpp
i2s_set_dac_mode(I2S_DAC_CHANNEL_RIGHT_EN);
i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, 44100);
```

And created a new function, `play_sound`.

Here's the complete code:

```cpp
// sound.cpp

#include <sound.h>

bool parseWavHeader(File &file, WavHeader &header) {
  if (file.read() != 'R' || file.read() != 'I' || file.read() != 'F' || file.read() != 'F') {
    Serial.println("Invalid WAV file");
    return false;
  }

  file.seek(22);
  header.num_channels = file.read() | (file.read() << 8);
  header.sample_rate = file.read() | (file.read() << 8) | (file.read() << 16) | (file.read() << 24);
  file.seek(34);
  header.bits_per_sample = file.read() | (file.read() << 8);
  file.seek(44);  // Skip to the audio data
  return true;
}

void setup_sound() {
  i2s_config_t i2s_config = {
      .mode = (i2s_mode_t)(I2S_MODE_MASTER | I2S_MODE_TX),
      .sample_rate = 44100,
      .bits_per_sample = I2S_BITS_PER_SAMPLE_16BIT,
      .channel_format = I2S_CHANNEL_FMT_ONLY_LEFT,
      .communication_format = I2S_COMM_FORMAT_I2S_MSB,
      .intr_alloc_flags = ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL1,
      .dma_buf_count = 8,
      .dma_buf_len = 1024,
      .use_apll = false,
      .tx_desc_auto_clear = true,
  };

  i2s_pin_config_t pin_config = {
      .bck_io_num = I2S_BCLK,
      .ws_io_num = I2S_LRC,
      .data_out_num = I2S_DOUT,
      .data_in_num = -1,
  };

  i2s_driver_install(I2S_NUM_0, &i2s_config, 0, NULL);
  i2s_set_pin(I2S_NUM_0, &pin_config);
}

void play_sound(std::string text, fs::FS &SD) {
  std::string filename = "/audios/" + text + ".wav";
  File file = SD.open(filename.c_str());
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    while (1) delay(1);
  }

  WavHeader header;
  if (!parseWavHeader(file, header)) {
    Serial.println("Invalid WAV file");
    return;
  }

  i2s_set_sample_rates(I2S_NUM_0, header.sample_rate);

  const size_t buffer_size = 512;
  uint8_t buffer[buffer_size];
  size_t bytes_read;
  size_t bytes_written;
  while (file.available() && (bytes_read = file.read(buffer, buffer_size)) > 0) {
    i2s_write(I2S_NUM_0, buffer, bytes_read, &bytes_written, portMAX_DELAY);
    if (bytes_read == 0) break;
  }

  file.close();
}
```

```cpp
// sound.h

#ifndef SOUND_H
#define SOUND_H

#include <SD.h>
#include <driver/i2s.h>

#define I2S_DOUT 25
#define I2S_BCLK 33
#define I2S_LRC 26

struct WavHeader {
  uint32_t sample_rate;
  uint16_t bits_per_sample;
  uint16_t num_channels;
};

bool parseWavHeader(File &file, WavHeader &header);
void setup_sound();
void play_sound(std::string text, fs::FS &SD);

#endif  // SOUND_H
```

Hope it helps you not go through the struggle I went through!

Comment: good job.
the another solution is to change the .sample_rate = 16000, can play well. for the file saved at same sample_rate.